# R finding the hourly mean difference from mean daily price from a complete history of market trades

Tags: r

I have a table of all of the trades on a market exchange for one security over a period of time.

```
Epoch        Date       Time     Price
1.452033e+12 2016-01-05 14:37:38 0.00220556
1.452033e+12 2016-01-05 14:37:31 0.00220888
1.452033e+12 2016-01-05 14:37:15 0.00220888
```

I want to see if there is any connection between price and time of day. My plan is to take mean price for each day and subtract it from each price for that day to get the difference from the mean. Then, for each hour interval, calculate the mean difference. Then, for each of the 24 hourly periods of the day, calculate the mean hourly mean difference.

So far I figured out how to use tapply() to get the mean price for each day. I could use `for` loops for everything else, but I want to learn the tricks for doing it more concisely in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the dplyr package you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(normalizedPrice = Price - mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

To do the same on an hourly basis, you can add a new column for 'hour of day' and perform a very similar operation:

```
df$hourOfDay <- format(df$Time, '%H') # You will need time in POSIXct format
df %>% group_by(hourOfDay) %>% mutate(normalizedHourOfDayPrice = Price - mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Note, if you leave time in the current format, you can also use `substr()` to extract hourOfDay.

You can also group by day and hourOfDay like this:

```
df %>% group_by(Date, hourOfDay) %>% mutate(normalizedDailyHourOfDayPrice = Price - mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And so on....does this work?

Comment: How do I install the package? I get `Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’`

Comment: you can use `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: Awesome, it worked! And now I know how to group things. just one question, why does it display the data types at the header?

Comment: That is a new feature in dplyr, which is actually a very good thing I think. :)